# Why all GC eligible objects are not destroyed, once GC runs?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If 1M objects are eligible for GC, some part of that object is destroyed when GC runs(i.e 20k objects). Why all GC eligible objects are not destroyed, once GC runs?

Comment: The garbage collector never “destroys” objects. It makes memory available for new allocations. If it managed to provide a sufficiently large memory block, it has done what it is supposed to do. It is entirely irrelevant, how many objects are “eligible for GC” or how many of them were in that particular memory block. In fact, any attempt to find out those numbers will already disturb the GC work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For example `G1` has a setting called `MaxGCPauseMillis`, that by default is `200ms`. The garbage collector algorithm can decide that out of 100 young regions that it has, it can do work on 80 of those, within that `200 ms` timeframe (based on statistics on previous collections). So instead of going through all of the regions, it will only work on some. Same thing happens on `G1` `mixed collections` - when young regions are scanned plus *some* old regions, not everything.

And Objects are not destroyed. A garbage collector algorithm scans *live* instances (starting from some GC roots) and everything that is left - is garbage. A typical collector will scan a certain region, find everything that is alive, move it to a different (empty) region - and that initial region will be marked as "empty", meaning nothing inside it that was left is needed anymore. This is called "garbage" now.

Answer (score 0):

As Holger said, GC does not destroy objects.
It simply try to collect all of the "unused" objects (according to some logic / algorithm, which can be configured), so a RAM Heap space will be available for allocating of new objects.

Comment: it is not even unused - a GC traverses _live_ instances and everything else is garbage.